# Firebase Cloud Function Error: Deadline exceeded (Flutter Push Notification)

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

So, I am trying to implement an automated push notification feature in my Flutter app using Firebase-cloud-functions.

I got this error in my Firebase Console:

```
Error: Deadline exceeded
    at Http2CallStream.call.on (/srv/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:68:41)
    at emitOne (events.js:121:20)
    at Http2CallStream.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at process.nextTick (/srv/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:71:22)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:219:9)
```

This is index.js of my Firebase Function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

var msgData

exports.offerTrigger = functions.firestore.document(
    'message/{messageID}'
).onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    msgData = snapshot.data();

    admin.firestore().collection('pushtokens').get().then(async (snapshots) => {
        var tokens = [];
        if (snapshots.empty) {
            console.log('No Devies');
        } else {
            for (var token of snapshots.docs) {
                tokens.push(token.data().devtoken);
            }

            var payload = {
                "notification": {
                    "title": msgData.buissnessName,
                    "body": msgData.messageValue,
                    "sound": "default"
                },
                "data": {
                    "sendername": msgData.buissnessName,
                    "message": msgData.messageValue,
                }
            }
            try {
                const response = await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload);
                console.log('Pushed them all');
            }
            catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        }
    })
})
```

That's how tokens get to save in Firestore:

[image]

This is how I tried to send Push Notification. But none of the users received it.

[image]

Comment: “Deadline Exceeded” happens because of its limits.
See this. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas
Maximum write rate to a document 1 per second
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-cloud-firestore-discuss/tGaZpTWQ7tQ/NdaDGRAzBgAJ

Comment: Thanks for pointing that our Parth. Tho I didn't actually get what "Maximum write rate to a document" mean? is it the number of tokens that get saved or something related to message collection? Can you please enlight me .

Comment: It simply means that per second, you cannot write more than once to the same document

Comment: And where in this setup I am writing more than once in a single second? Is in the message document?  

Comment: @RajDhakad Did you find the source of this problem?

Comment: Yes @MarcusGallegos In my case my app has exhausted free service that firebase's free plan offers. Like my app had more than 50k requests, so cloud functions stopped working as well.

Comment: I got this error even with billing active and not reaching 5k reads, not reaching writes limit as well. And this is happening for about 3 hours and then everything is back to normal (happened last week and is happening now again). Have no idea what is happening. Any ideas?

Comment: @kavain It's not just the total number of reads in a day but also the number of reads in one second. Maybe you are exceeding the number of reads in 1 second limit

Comment: I believe I found out what it was, actually it gives this errors when a timeout happens as well, the problem probably was a deadlock (some research gave me this tip). So I don't know exactly why, but I killed the process, tried again and everything went back to normal.

Comment: oh! That's nice, happy for you